# What is the best way to add views to layout from code in android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-view, android-inflate

I have `loop` in my code to add `Views` to the `Layout`, the following code is a `Loop which is present in another loop` and i have so many loops like this, `Activity takes so much time to start` how to handle this ?

```
foreach (InfoQuery item in InfoList)
        {


            if (item == "kitten")
            {
                if (!done)
                {
                    TextView view= new TextView(ApplicationContext);
                    view.LayoutParameters = mainLayout.LayoutParameters;
                    view.TextSize = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Sp, 3, ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                    view.SetPadding((int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 10, ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics), 0, (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 10, ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics), 0);
                    view.Text = item.position;
                    layout2.AddView(view,0);
                    done = true;
                }

                TextView view2= new TextView(ApplicationContext);
                view2.LayoutParameters = mainLayout.LayoutParameters;
                view2.TextSize = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Sp, 3, ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics); ;
                view2.SetPadding((int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 30, ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics), 0, (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 10, ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics), 0);
                view2.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
                view2.Text = item.position;
                layout2.AddView(view2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Better to use a RecyclerView as suggested below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding a giant set of items to a layout in Android.  Use a recyclerview or listview instead.  Adding all the views, in addition to being slow, takes a ton of RAM, and a lot of time to draw even though it isn't on screen.